# Get a list of all items with a object value from a list, but the value has to exist at least 3 times

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say we have a list of cities. Each city knows their country.

Now I want to have a list of all cities of a random country, with there being at least 3 cities in that country.

My best guess is to try to solve this with linq. My idea is that I start by grouping the cities by country

```cs
List<City> cities = AssumeWeHaveAPopulatedList();

cities.GroupBy(c => c.country)
```

But now, how do I filter out those groups with less than 3 items in it?

And how do I then pick a random one of the groups and ungroup that one group again to get the desired list of cities for a random country which has at least 3 cities in that list?

Or maybe there is a different approach without grouping the cities by country first?

Comment: Well, each element in the result of `GroupBy` is an `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`, which implements `IEnumerable<TElement>`. If you just *started* with an `IEnumerable<TElement>`, how would you check its size?

Comment: @JonSkeet I never really understood the data structures from GroupBy results, but I think I get it now. It's basically turning it into a dictionary, mapping the grouped value to all items with the given value. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Count()` to filter by countries that have >= 3 cities and `Random` to pick a random city

Presuming that `Country` is a `string` property:

```
Random r = new Random();
List<IGrouping<string, City>> countryGroups = cities
    .GroupBy(c => c.Country)
    .Where(cg => cg.Count() >= 3)
    .ToList();
IGrouping<string, City> randomCountryCity = countryGroups[r.Next(countryGroups.Count)];
```

So now you have a random group of country-cities. If you want to flatten them to get the Cities in this group, just use it as `IEnumerable<City>` which it already implements:

```
List<City> randomCityList = randomCountryCity.ToList();
```

Sidenote: I omitted the validation part, you have to ensure that `countryGroups` contains `Any` items, otherwise you can't access a random one.

Answer (score 2):

A group works like a list, so you can just check the count of the groups:

```
cities.GroupBy(c => c.country).Where(g => g.Count() >=3)
```

You can then flatten the groups by using SelectMany

```
var result = cities
                .GroupBy(c => c.country)
                .Where(g => g.Count() >=3)
                .SelectMany(g => g)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use count of the Grouped list like follow:

```
var newlist = cities.GroupBy(c => c.country)
                    .Where(x=>x.Count()>=3)
                    .Select(x=>new { country=x.Key , CityCount=x.Count()})
                    .ToList();
```